# My script is not working in my table edit modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code for modal inside of data tables this modal is for edit but my script only works at first row but if i want to edit the second row the script is not working.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="leave_type">Type of Leave:</label>
        <select class="form-control mylist1" id="mylist1" name="leave_type">
            <option value="Vacation Leave">Vacation Leave</option>
            <option value="Maternity Leave" >Maternity Leave</option>
            <option value="Sick Leave" >Sick Leave</option>
            <option value="Paternity Leave" >Paternity Leave</option>
            <option value="Leave Without Pay" >Leave Without Pay</option>
            <option value="Authorized Absence" >Authorized Absence</option>
            <option value="Unauthorized Absence" >Unauthorized Absence</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="forshow1" class="forshow1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script

```
  <script>
     $('#mylist1').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 'Other'){
            $('#forshow1').append('<input type="text" name="other" class="form- 
            control" id="myInput1" />');
        }else{
            $('#myInput1').remove();
        }
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function(){
  if( $(this).val() == 'Other'){
     $('#forshow1').append('<input type="text" name="other" class="form- 
     control" id="myInput1" />');
  }else{
     $('#myInput1').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```js
$('#mylist1').change(function(){ 
    if( $(this).val() == 'Other'){
     $('#forshow1').append('<input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" id="myInput1" />');
  }else{
     $('#myInput1').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="leave_type">Type of Leave:</label>
        <select class="form-control mylist1" id="mylist1" name="leave_type">
            <option value="Vacation Leave">Vacation Leave</option>
            <option value="Maternity Leave" >Maternity Leave</option>
            <option value="Sick Leave" >Sick Leave</option>
            <option value="Paternity Leave" >Paternity Leave</option>
            <option value="Leave Without Pay" >Leave Without Pay</option>
            <option value="Authorized Absence" >Authorized Absence</option>
            <option value="Unauthorized Absence" >Unauthorized Absence</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="forshow1" class="forshow1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Alfredo Ramirez Jr.